# Why are the number of profile views displayed?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

Is there a reason why the number of profile views is displayed when I go to my profile? I don't think it is a bad thing, I just don't see the purpose.

Comment: Well, the reason is that the decision is written into the code for the software.  But that's kind of tautological.  It sounds like you're asking why the SE developers made that decision.  It's a measure of curiosity.  Some people have lots of views because they're "famous" (for mathematicians) and others because they're really aggressively annoying.  It's a curious measurement. There's probably other reasons!

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/76903/popularity-contest